# Adding a combo box or drop-down list to UIView

Tags: iphone, combobox, uiview, interface-builder

I need to add a combo box or drop-down list to a UIView. I did not find such an object in the "Library" of the interface builder. How do I add this object to my UIVIEW? Do I have to inherit it from another object (which one?) or do I have to create it from scratch programmatically?
Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard practice here is to either use a UIPicker or push a TableViewController to the stack and return once the user has selected an option here.

Comment: Thanx, I concidered using  UIPicker but its "slot machine" look doesnt seem appropriate for my applicTION. I'll have to make a custom object, using a UITableView. Thanx for your help (-:

Comment: just use an action sheet, so easy

Answer (score 2):

Youll prolly want to use the UIPicker class as there is no DropDown in UIKit, you can always make your own dropdown list  if you desire