# iPhone ComboBox?

Tags: iphone, combobox

Is there a way to make ComboBox on the iPhone ?
I know there is no standard controller for ComboBox. 
But I am thinking custom controller instead of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There probably is, but the UIPickerView is what Apple intended us to use instead :)

Comment: Thanks. I am searching like this :
http://isnipe.webdiligence.ca/images/PNG/screens-1.2/Picture-1.png

I don't know whether this calls UIPicker on another screen, when user touches on the combo.

Is it possible to make combo like on the above link ?

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155477/adding-a-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-to-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIPickerView` is the control that would normally be a combo box. See Apple's documentation for information on how to use it. It works similar to `UITableView`s.

Comment: Thanks. I am searching like this :
http://isnipe.webdiligence.ca/images/PNG/screens-1.2/Picture-1.png

I don't know whether this calls UIPicker on another screen, when user touches on the combo.

Is it possible to make combo like on the above link ?

Thanks.

Comment: It will most definitely show a `UIPickerView`. To get a visual appearance like a combo box prior to clicking on it, just mock up your own images and use it as background for a button.