# Creating a drop down list

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, controls, drop-down-menu

I want to make a drop-down list from scratch. Can anyone please tell me how to do so?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155477/adding-a-combo-box-or-drop-down-list-to-uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would start with a UITextField and a button to look like a normal closed drop down list. Then when the button is clicked I would add a new view containing a small UITableView for the drop down part. It shouldn't be too hard. However I'd reconsider the need for a drop down box. Its just not something that you have room on screen for, and the UIPickerView is better suited IMHO. Now on the iPad they use a drop down similar to what I described above but it has enough room on the screen to make this practical.

Comment: even easier, just use an action sheet

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIPickerView or a UITableView to have a functionality akin to drop down lists.