# How to create a dropDownList which work as NSPopUpButton in objcetive c?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to create a drop down list which is similar to NSPopUpButton dynamically for iPhone applications. I know in interface builder we have picker view but i have need looks like a drop-down list or NSPopUpButton. How i create that? How we create function which is similar to cocoa app in iPhone app? I also know Cocoa used for mac OS  but i want to create same as for iPhone so i ask this question?

Comment: Before -ve vote my question please give comment as reason so i can improve my ability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement drop down box in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889804/how-to-implement-drop-down-box-in-iphone)